# Using Visual Studio Code with Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I want to use Visual Studio Code as script editor with Unity3D on MacOS.

I can open the main folder, I have Intellisens working, but VSCode can't find UnityEngine and all Unity objects.
I'm not so familiar with VSCode so I don't know where to look at first.

Comment: There's not enough info here to say what the problem is. However, you can grab vs with unity when installing, I'd imagine it's been updated for vs 2017 :)

Comment: You're right, but I don't know what to precise, launch.json ?

Comment: I cant give you an answer as I do not work on a Mac, but that sounds as if you are missing the references to the Unity DLL's, you say you are `opening a main folder` which does not sounds like `opening the generated project`. which could very well explain the missing references.

Comment: Did you follow these steps? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity You should be able to double-click a script file within unity, and it will setup vscode for you.

Comment: Yes, I did. Now it works with a new project, but not yet with an existing one.

Comment: I found the problem, my project had already a .sln file because it came from windows. I guess VSCode did not generate its own. I have deleted every vs file and reopened it and know it works. Thanks everyone !

Answer (score 0):

You should need to install unity code exention for VS. Here is the offical VS guide: [**Unity Development with VS Code**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRhJ5.gif)

**Unity Extensions**

The community is continually developing more and more valuable extensions for Unity. Here are some popular extensions that you might find useful. You can search for more extensions in the [**VS Code Extension Marketplace**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=Unity&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance).

[image: [1]: https://code.visualst]udio.com/docs/other/unity